# Installing a package outside current resolver

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I'm using `stack` `lts-9.0` snapshot, which includes `process-1.4.X`. Due to some problems with this version, I would like to use `process-1.6.1.0`. Adding this version to `extra-deps` does not seem to be enough:

```
extra-deps:
- process-1.6.1.0
```

since this will cause the following error:

```
Error: While constructing the build plan, the following exceptions were encountered:

In the dependencies for Cabal-1.24.2.0:
    process-1.6.1.0 must match >=1.1.0.1 && <1.5 (latest applicable is 1.4.3.0)
```

What do I need to do in these cases?

Comment: Just tested with a sample repo and it seemed to work fine for me. can you share your cabal and stack file (or your repo if possible) ?

Comment: Why do people keep asking this? The whole point of Stack is to use an exact choice of package versions that _have been proven to work together everywhere_. If you want to select package versions yourself, don't use Stack, use Cabal-install instead. Of course that has its risks, though not as much anymore [with its new Nix-style building mode](http://blog.ezyang.com/2016/05/announcing-cabal-new-build-nix-style-local-builds/).

Comment: I use `stack` because it makes it easy to build and deploy Haskell projects, specially for somebody who is not a `cabal` or `nix` expert. However, sometimes I need to use a package that fixes a nasty bug, and I don't know how to go about it. Does that mean that I have to stop using `stack`? I don't know ...

Comment: @Sibi [this is the repo](https://github.com/capitanbatata/sandbox/tree/master/racing-turtles). Maybe I'm using a too-old LTS (`9.0`).?

Comment: @DamianNadales Which directory are  you trying to build inside the repo ?

Comment: @leftaroundabout The `extra-deps` is a supported workflow in Stack and I don't see any problem with it - So this is a valid question. Also, I'm sort of forced to use stack (in preference to Cabal-install) because of it's other features like `--file-watch`, docker support and specifying git as an external dependency.

Comment: @Sibi The `racing-turtles` directory.

Comment: This is an error you get when one of your dependencies requires an older version of process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As written in the message, the problem is with [`Cabal-1.24.2.0` depending on `process < 1.5`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/Cabal-1.24.2.0).
Add `Cabal-2.0.0.2` to the `extra-deps`.

Comment: I missed that one! Thanks. BTW, is there a way to automatically, detect the changes needed to `extra-deps`. I tried `stack solver` with no luck...

Comment: I think `Cabal` might be some kind of exception. Usually `stack solver` does the job. It may be worth reporting that issue to stack.